# Retrieving the array of selected values in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I have the following issue where i cannot retrieve the selected array from select2 in my JS.

```html
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple"
        name="states[]"
        multiple="multiple"
        style="width:500px;">

  <option>"dynamic value"</option>
  <option>"dynamic value2"</option>
```

And the associated script:

```js
var caseCodes = $('.js-example-basic-multiple option:selected').text()
```

The above javascript function retrieves all my selected values as a single long string.

Is there any way i can retrieve the array and loop through it to find each individual selected value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read the `<select>`'s value :

```
$('.js-example-basic-multiple').val()
```